# An object created separately by different threads is still shared

Tags: c#, parallel.foreach

I have a program in which I want to Simulate a queue. To speed things up (lots of different parameters) I thought that I could use a parallel loop, however the queue object (or at least the objects within that object) are still shared while they are all created within either the MGcC function or the queue object. Is there something I forgot about parallel functions?

The object which gives the trouble is the queue.MyHeap.

(Also if more information is needed please ask as I have left out a lot to make it more readably as you might see in the queue object).

```
Parallel.ForEach(a, (numbers) =>
{                   
    MGcC(a);
});        

static public Tuple<Customer[,], List<Interval>[]> MGcC(int a)
{
    Queue queue = new Queue(a);
    return queue.Simulate(writeFile);
}

public class Queue
{
    Func<object, double> arrivalFunction;
    Func<object, double> servingFunction;
    double lambda;
    double v;
    object serviceObject;
    int minServers;
    bool decision;

    int idleServers;
    int activeServers;
    int amountInOrbit;
    protected minHeap myHeap;

    public Queue(double lambda, double v, object serviceObject, int servers, Func<object, double> arrivalFunction, Func<object, double> servingFunction, bool decision = false)
    {
        this.arrivalFunction = arrivalFunction;
        this.servingFunction = servingFunction;
        this.lambda = lambda;
        this.v = v;
        this.serviceObject = serviceObject;
        this.minServers = servers;
        this.decision = decision;

        idleServers = servers;
        activeServers = 0;
        amountInOrbit = 0;
        myHeap = new minHeap();
    }

public class minHeap
{
    static protected Action[] heap;
    static public int counter;
    public minHeap()
    {
        counter = -1;
        heap = new Action[1000000];
    }

    public Action Pop()
    {
        if (counter < 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("empty");
            return new Action(0, 0, new Customer());
        }
        Action returnValue = heap[0];
        heap[0] = heap[counter];
        counter--;
        heapify(0);
        return (returnValue);
    }

    public void Push(Action a)
    {
        counter++;
        heap[counter] = new Action(double.PositiveInfinity, 0, new Customer());
        InsertKey(counter, a);
    }

    static void InsertKey(int i, Action a)
    {
        if (heap[i].TimeOfExecution < a.TimeOfExecution)
            Console.WriteLine("should not have happened");
        heap[i] = a;
        while (i > 0 && heap[Parent(i)].TimeOfExecution > heap[i].TimeOfExecution)
        {
            Action temp = heap[i];
            heap[i] = heap[Parent(i)];
            heap[Parent(i)] = temp;
            i = Parent(i);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Which part of the `minHeap` is being shared? It doesn't use static fields by any chance?

Comment: what is the symptom that makes you think that something is being shared? what could we do to reproduce something being shared here, so we can understand what is happening?

Comment: The only thing I see shared is `writeFile` are you attempting to write to the same file from multiple threads?

Comment: MarcGravell The heap having multiple arrival objects. being empty. MeName It does, the list and counter (is that bad?).

Comment: juharr, the file to write to is also different per thread

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All the fields on your `minHeap` type are `static`. So yes: they're shared - that's what `static` means. You probably want to make them non-`static`.

Possibly you used `static` when you meant `readonly`?

Comment: Yup that was the problem (still used to add static to must things as a beginner). Thanks

Comment: @R.vW oh yeah, get out of that habit ASAP; it is *very* unlikely that you want to use `static` all that often